# IntelliJ: Search structurally in different projects

Tags: intellij-idea

Structural search in IntelliJ IDEA is not only powerful, but also not trivial at all to get right. Now when I have created a working template of my own, I might want to use it in multiple projects.

I do not see a way to save globally. Is there anything I can do short of copying the relevant bits from one `workspace.xml` to another?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-18846

Comment: OK, fine, thanks you, Serge. I know you don’t need the points, but this is actually the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, it's not supported at the moment, please [follow this feature request for updates](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-18846).